# Why there is Segmentation Fault in this code

Tags: c++

Question is -
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3PxUo.png)

Answer is -

```
void solve(SinglyLinkedListNode* head, int &positionFromTail, int &ans){
    if(head == NULL){
        return;
    }
    head = head->next;
    solve(head, positionFromTail, ans);
    if(positionFromTail == 0){
        ans = head->data;
    }
    positionFromTail--;
}

int getNode(SinglyLinkedListNode* llist, int positionFromTail) {
    int ans = -1;
    solve(llist, positionFromTail, ans);
    return ans;
}
```

but this answer is giving segmentation fault

```
void solve(SinglyLinkedListNode* head, int &positionFromTail, int &ans){
    if(head == NULL){
        return;
    }
    // head = head->next;
    solve(head->next, positionFromTail, ans);
    if(positionFromTail == 0){
        ans = head->data;
    }
    positionFromTail--;
}

int getNode(SinglyLinkedListNode* llist, int positionFromTail) {
    int ans = -1;
    solve(llist, positionFromTail, ans);
    return ans;
}
```

This answer is not giving segmentation fault.

Why this is happening

Comment: you've changed `head` so it might be null in `head->data`

Comment: The two `solve` functions do different things. Before the recursive call to `solve` one function modifies where `head` is pointing, while the other does not.

Comment: [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems)

Comment: head is not `NULL`, ok so you can do `head = head->next;`, now you dont know if `head` is `NULL` or not, so `ans = head->data;` potentially dereferences a nullpointer. In the other code. `ans = head->data` cannot possibly dereference a nullpointer, because you checked that `head` is not a nullpointer

Comment: please read about [mcve]. One can guess what the problem is and most likely we guessed right, but strictly speaking without the missing code one cannot be sure. One could even add missing pieces such that your "ok" code crashes and your crashing code does not.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're changing the value of `head` to point to `head->next` and this may be null in the `if` statement.

```
head = head->next; // You've changed head, if may now be null
solve(head, positionFromTail, ans);
if(positionFromTail == 0){
    ans = head->data; // You're de-referencing head, which may be null
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's simple:
Here you checking if head is not NULL pointer

```
void solve(SinglyLinkedListNode* head, int &positionFromTail, int &ans){
    if(head == NULL){
        return;
    }
```

But then trying to set head pointing to `head->next` there:

```
head = head->next;
```

And instead of checking `head->next` not being NULL here you already trying to get `head->next` one more time here

```
solve(head->next, positionFromTail, ans);
```

which is actually, combining with previous line, becomes `head->next->next`. So if here middle `next` is NULL - !BANG!, you get SegFault